# Why does Chart.js render funky?

Tags: chart.js

When rendering a chart with Chart.js, the output just looks super strange.

- The left side only has one label
- The popover is... interesting
- The bottom legend has overlapping labels
- Colors flicker on hover

https://codepen.io/freakypie/pen/JjYPwjp

```
    "labels": [
        "Wed Apr 8"
    ],
    "datasets": [{
            "label": "#3",
            "data": [
                33756
            ],
            "backgroundColor": "hsl(195, 70%, 20%)",
        },
        {
            "label": "#4",
            "data": [
                41100
            ],
            "backgroundColor": "hsl(277.5, 70%, 20%)",
        },
        {
            "label": "#5",
            "data": [
                56430
            ],
            "backgroundColor": "hsl(30, 70%, 20%)",
        },
    ]
};

var options = {
    animation: false,
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: {
        position: 'bottom',
    },
};

new Chart('chart', {
    type: 'bar',
    options: options,
    data: data
});
```

[image: Chartjs output]

Comment: leech, I can't seem to reproduce the issue in the code pen. It looks perfectly fine for some reason...Can you tell me what browser you're using?

Comment: I checked on other browsers, and you are right, it shows up fine.

I turned off my ad-blocker and presto, the graph looked fine

Comment: Ad blocker huh? now THAT is odd. Which browser was causing the issue?

Comment: In this particular case, it was: Brave. Just using their stock blocking

Comment: Hey Leech. This conversation actually sparked me to check out brave as a browser. I gotta say, it's pretty damn slick. I am happy I ended up looking at this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears this is a browser related issue. We may be able to apply some browser specific CSS to counter this issue.